# vscode c/c++ define configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get a c project configured in vscode. Basically, I'm on MacOS but IntelliSense thinks that the MS_WINDOWS macro is defined, so it's always trying to include the windows.h header. A few questions:

How can I see a list of macros that IntelliSense thinks are defined and where they come from?

How can I undefine the MS_WINDOWS macro in c_cpp_properties.json? I tried putting "MS_WINDOWS=0" in configurations.defines but that doesn't work because MS_WINDOWS is still defined.

Answer (score 0):

may be: 
"intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"